# Data-driven breadcrumb based on hierarchical (parent-child) data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js, mariadb

I would like to create a *breadcrumb* for my site that is completely data-driven.

The data is stored using MariaDB and looks like this:

```
parent_id | parent_name | child_id | child_name
———————————————————————————————————————————————
    1     |     AAA     |    101   |    aaa
    1     |     Aaa     |    102   |    bbb
    1     |     Aaa     |    103   |    ccc
   101    |     aaa     |   1001   |   aaaa
   101    |     aaa     |   1002   |   bbbb
   102    |     bbb     |   1004   |   cccc
   102    |     bbb     |   1005   |   dddd    
    2     |     Bbb     |    104   |    ddd
```

If I select let say record with id='1005', I want my *breadcrumb* to look like `1 / 102 / 1005`
Equivalent HTML is:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">102</a></li>
        <li>1005</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, selecting

- '1002' updates the *breadcrumb* to `1 / 101 / 1002`
- '104' updates the *breadcrumb* to `2 / 104`
- …

Comment: so far all we have here is a statement of intent but no code that attempts to solve the problem. Please add the code that you have tried and explain what is going on/wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.

Firstly, I changed the table structure, based on the suggestions mentioned in [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). As a result, I changed my data structure to:

```
    id  |     name    |   lft    |   rgt
—————————————————————————————————————————————
     1  |     AAA     |     1    |    16
   101  |     aaa     |     2    |     7
  1001  |     aaaa    |     3    |     4
  1002  |     bbbb    |     5    |     6
   102  |     bbb     |     8    |    13
  1004  |     cccc    |     9    |    10
  1005  |     dddd    |    11    |    12
   103  |     ccc     |    14    |    15
     2  |     BBB     |    17    |    20
   104  |     ddd     |    18    |    19
```

Then using php, I can easily extract the data from the table in almost the correct format with the following SQL-statement (where '$id' is a variable and depending on the user selection as mentioned earlier):

```
SELECT parent.id, parent.name
FROM
  table AS node,
  table AS parent
WHERE
  node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
AND
  node.id = '$id'
ORDER BY
  parent.lft;
```

Finally, using d3.js, I can use the following code the create the HTML:

```
d3.json('php/breadcrumb.php?id=' + id).get(function(error, d_breadcrumb) {

  var ul = d3.select('#breadcrumb').append('ul')
    .attr('class', 'breadcrumb');

  ul.selectAll('li')
    .data(d_breadcrumb)
    .enter()
    .append('li')
      .append('a')
        .attr('href', function(d) {
          return '?id=' + d.id;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
});
```